# How to dynamic bind a Control in a GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I use asp.net 4 c#.

I have a gridview, inside a Label. I would like to know how to BIND the `Text` property for the first label to the dictionary KEY and the second to dictionary VALUE, without using the gridview event `DataBound` or similar.

Please suggest an example, thanks

```
   <asp:GridView ID="uxContentByYearMonths" runat="server">
        <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Month">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="uxMonth" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Key") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>

            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Total Content">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="uxCount" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Value") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>

// DataSource
Dictionary<int, int> result = new Dictionary<int, int>();
```

Comment: Consider using ObjectDataSource for your GridView. There are lot of examples on the web about what it is and how use it.

Comment: Thanks Lucasus for your suggestion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Dictionary<int, int> result = new Dictionary<int, int>();

uxContentByYearMonths.DataSource = from item in result 
                      select new { Key = item.Key, Value = item.Value };

uxContentByYearMonths.DataBind();
```

you can find many examples from here [Bind NameValueCollection to GridView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/217356/bind-namevaluecollection-to-gridview)